# Generally speaking, how do I extend IIS and add a custom control panel icon?

Tags: iis, windows-7, iis-7, windows-server-2008

I would like to extend IIS in a manner similar to the way this product does in the "other" section.

[image]

How do I go about extending IIS to support my own custom handler / icon?  Specifically, this handler forces single sign on for a website, and provides its own HTTPS log in screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have an API in an assmebly called Microsoft.Web.Management.dll, it uses WinForms.
Long story short: You implement a ModuleProvider derived class and register it in Administration.config (windir\system32\inetsrv\config), the ModuleProvider specifies the Module to load in the client (GetModuleDefinition) and in its initialization it registers a ModulePage (there are a few options, ModuleListPage, ModulePropertiesPage, ModuleDialogPage, and ModulePage).
So:
Develop service-side functionality using:
 - ModuleProvider
 - ModuleService

Develop client-side functionality using:
 - Module
 - ModuleServiceProxy
 - ModulePage
 - and Any additional extensions

I have one example posted at:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosag/archive/2007/05/11/extendingiismanagerhomepage.aspx

and also a simple example at:
http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/269/how-to-create-a-simple-iis-manager-module/

and another example at: http://www.carlosag.net/Tools/MRUModule/